# Accessing large number of JSON assets with Flutter

Tags: android, json, dart, flutter

I'm working on a prototype app that would read and display data from a large repository of JSON files.  I'm currently wondering about the best way to model this behavior in the pubspec.yaml and the in the flutter code itself.

Right now I'm initially loading a catalog file in JSON, this creates a scrollable listview of catalog entries, each of those has its own JSON file in a subdirectory (relative to the catalog file).  Do I need to add each new file to the pubspec.yaml, or can I just directly access them.

Comment: shouldn't you use an API for that instead of having everything locally ? You don't want to redeploy your app everytimes you make a little change in your JSON

Comment: This is a large collection of encoded ancient texts, they're very static.  I'm not worried about them changing often.  But size is a bit of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just access files in the file system without specifying the files in the `pubspec.yaml`.

Im not sure, if the syntax is still correct, because it is an old project I worked on but it should work in a similar way.

```
File _themeFile;
Future<Null> _loadThemeFile() async {
  String dir = (await PathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  _themeFile = new File('$dir/theme.txt');
  if (!await _themeFile.exists()) {
    _themeFile.create();
    await _themeFile.writeAsString(JSON.encode({
      'theme': 'dark',
      'colorIndex': 0,
      'displayDone': true,
    }));
  }
}
```

This snippet looks for the file with the name `theme.txt` and returns it. If it does not exist, it creates the file. You wouldn't probably need this exactly like that, but I think you can use it as a starting point.

Comment: This is great and seems logical, quick clarifying question would this work with the gradle packaging system to make sure the files are bundled in a final APK?